# How to declare an object that contains a mapping of two other objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, api, javascript-objects

I have a document in my Firestone project that contains some object (map):

```
My_map = {
    first_name: *some_id,
    last_name: *some_other_id
    ...
}
```

In addition to that, I have some API that returns a corresponding object but with some different property names:

```
My_api_object = {
    cus_name: *some value*,
    cus_last_name: *some other value*,
    ...
}
```

I declared some combined object that has each property from my_map, mapped to some property in `my_api_object` like that (the declaration is static and made by Me):

```
Combined_object: {
    first_name: "cus_name",
    last_name: "cus_last_name"
}
```

I want to run with `foreach` loop on the combined_object and do some operations with it on both `my_api_object`
And `my_map` objects.

I don't want to put the combined object in the same file where I perform the foreach loop, I want to move the combined_object to some external `shared/models.js` file and later use it anywhere in my code.
The question is, how should I declare the combined_object? As an interface, as an enums?

Thanks for the help,

Michael

Comment: The simplest way would be to use the same names in your database and your internal "api object", removing the need for your "combined object" altogether. You're free to name your variables however you like, so why make life more difficult for yourself? Now if you have some specific reason in mind, you would increase your chances of getting an answer by telling us more about it.

Comment: Hi kuroi, The problem is that I get few other objects similar to the API object. I call 3 different API urls, the first returns "customer_name" property, the second "cus_name" and the third is "customerName"

Comment: all the 3 API calls are static, which means I know what they return, I just need some combined object model to make the mapping much simple, in an external file of course, I'm not sure if I should use enums for that

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're trying to do, but if your problem is to convert various database records into elements of a unique Firestore table, maybe this could help?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter

Comment: I suggest you edit your original post to add more details.

Comment: ok, i will explain:
i have this code duplicated 20 times:
    let field= fields.find(
                    f => f.id == payment_fields_collection["****firebase_property1..20"]
                )
                if (field && field .value) {
                    data["*****api_property1..20"] = field.value
                }

i wanna do something like that in an external file and run on it using foreach loop:
this_specific_API_ = {
firebase_property1: api_property1
firebase_property2: api_property2
...
} 

should i use enums or just a regular object?

Comment: ok, i will edit the original post